# After Effects Blur Effect with Mask Doesn't Go to the Edge

Tags: after-effects

I'm new to After Effects and I'm trying to blur a section of a video using masks and tracking.

Everything is working fine, but for some reason the blur effect (and this is the same with other effects too) doesn't go to the very edge of the video. This only happens for the right edge of the video.

Does anyone know what might be causing this?

Picture:

[image: Mask Stopping Near Edge]

What I would like is everything inside the orange mask to be blurred. If I resize and move the mask around, it can blur everything, except for the right edge as shown in the picture. Making a new mask has the same result. Example below:

[image: New Mask Same Problem]

Any help greatly appreciated.

Comment: Strange… Is the blur effect applied to the footage layer, or an adjustment layer. If it's an adjustment layer you could check to see that it hasn't accidentally been nudged off-centre.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you applied the blur to an adjustment layer (as you should), check to make sure the layer is positioned in the center of the composition. Hit 'P' on the adjustment layer and right click on the 'Position' name and Reset it.

Check the mask expansion to see if maybe you have it set to a number less than or greater than 0. I doubt this is the issue as when you recreate a mask the problem doesn't persist.

If you haven't applied the blur to an adjustment layer you should do that and see if it fixes your issue.